# How can we do object filtering in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When defining an object context, using code first in entity framework, for example:

```
public class DomainContext : DbContext
{
    public DomainContext() { }
    public virtual DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

We all know that you can query "News" doing something like (for example, to get all news that were published today):

```
var ctx = new DomainContext();
ctx.News.Where(x => x.PublishedDate == DateTime.Now.Date)
```

But, and this is the question: Is there a way to apply a pre-defined filtering/condition to all queries that pass through `ctx.News`? Say that I wanted that all queries on `ctx.News` to have the "Published Today" filtering implicit applied?

Comment: Why not add a property NewsToday that returns the result of a 'news of today' query? Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882532.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to add automatic condition (filter) to querying news. All posted examples work but only if you query `News` directly. If you for example loads navigation property pointing to `News` examples will fail.

EDMX solve this by [conditional mapping](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/using-conditional-mapping) but this leads to other very bad disadvantages. Conditional mapping is fixed (cannot be changed without rebuilding model) and you can have only single condition for each type - it is like TPH degraded to single entity type. Moreover conditions defined in conditional mapping probably cannot work with "Today". Conditional mapping is not available in code-first approach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a way to add a filter to the `DbSet<News>` object as you're suggesting. But what you should be able to do is just write another function:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<News> TodaysNews
{
    get { return News.WHere(n => n.PublishDate == DateTime.Today); } 
}
```

And then, I think, if you did a query on top of that somewhere else, like:

```
var todaysGoodNews = from n in ctx.TodaysNews
                     where n.IsGood == true
                     select n;
```

then it would combine the queries when it sent it to the server rather than making it two separate queries. I'm not positive if that works when you use `IEnumerable<>` or if you need to return something else (`IQueryable<>`, perhaps?).

**Edit:**

I just saw your response to the other poster below. I guess I took too long to type/format. I don't know of any way to apply a filter like that, but aren't our solutions effectively doing that? You could even make TodaysNews be the only way to directly access that object through the context or something.

Comment: Well, it sort of work. But it's a bit more complicated then that, I want to be able to "hide" the normal "News" from the rest of the application automatically (this is not one specific application, it's a general sollution that is to be re-used company wide as a library basically).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new property to your context:

```
public IEnumerable<News> TodaysNews
{
    get
    {
        return this.News.Where(x => x.PublishedDate == DateTime.Now.Date);
    }
}
```

Any further filtering/sorting/etc can then be applied to the property.

**Update:**

If you're not able to just use a pre-filtered query, another option is to create a *view* in your database and map your entity to that view.  The view could be based on the current date.

Comment: Correct, but that's not what I'm after sadly. Is there no way to apply an implicit query filtering to all objects of a specific type from within EF?

Comment: See my update.  Maybe using entity mapping to a view would work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and I found this: [EntityFramework.Filters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Filters/). [This post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/) shows how to use it.

Comment: EntityFramework.Filters library has some issues with the filters values lifecycle (see the issues section). EntityFramework.DynamicFilters (https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) doesn't have these issues, but it requires to model the FKs as properties in the entity classes.